# npm link interdependent local packages (A->B->C) with common dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-link

I have three packages I am developing locally:

- @AcmeOrg/A (the host-app)
- @AcmeOrg/B (the sub-app)
- @AcmeOrg/C (a feature for the sub-app)

A depends on B, B depends on C

All 3 have a few common "peer" dependencies: i.e `React` and some other React-based packages.

All 3 use the `watch` functionality of `webpack` to recompile on changes. I want to develop all three simultaneously.

Initially, I tried through NPM link:

```sh
# in @AcmeOrg/C
npm link # make this package linkable
npm run watch
```

```sh
# in @AcmeOrg/B
npm link # make this package linkable
npm link @AcmeOrg/C # link to the local copy of @AcmeOrg/C
npm run watch
```

```sh
# in @AcmeOrg/A
npm link @AcmeOrg/B # link to the local copy of @AcmeOrg/B
npm run watch
```

This gets *most* of the way there - I can see all 3 packages recompiling on changes.

However, in-browser, I am seeing this React error triggered by code exported from `C` and imported in `B`:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and
>    fix this

Doing this helped a bit:

```sh
# in @AcmeOrg/C
npm link ../path/to/B/node_modules/react
```

...but it seems like I need to do this for every single common dependency between the two packages. i.e any common dependency that creates a React `ContextProvider`.

**Questions:**

- is there a better way than the above to locally link packages, without having to worry about the common peer dependencies between them?